# Can I serialise a NSManagedObject?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I need to send an object (NSManagedObject (NSMO) subclass) up to a web service and retrieve it later. I was hoping I could somehow serialise it, but I'm hoping not to have to jump through the encoding hoops.

I can convert a simple NSMO object into a dictionary using:
`[instance dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:instance.entity.attributesByName.allKeys];`

However, my NSMO is a number of levels deep in terms of relationships to other NSMOs. What would be the best way to create a full serialised version of the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this in a general way, you could write a recursive method `serializedDictionary` (either in a subclass of NSManagedObject or in a category) which:

1. Creates an empty NSMutableDictionary.
2. For each *property*, adds the key and value to the dictionary.
3. For each *relationship*, adds the relationship name as key and then calls `serializedDictionary` on the object and adds that as the value. If it's a to-many relationship, you'll have to put those values in an NSArray.

Note that if it's at all possible for a child object to be related back up to a parent (which is very possible if you have inverse relationships like Core Data recommends) you will either need to whitelist the relationships you save (easier) or pass along a set to keep track of which objects have already been serialized, so you don't encode them again (harder, I don't recommend this).

Comment: Thanks very much. I like the idea of  making a recursive method for getting the dictionaries. I think what I'll do when the service returns the data, though, is not deserialise it back into a NSMO, but keep it in its dictionary form instead since the app only needs to display the historic data and no longer needs to keep a track. That way I won't need to worry about the inverse relationships either. Also, I think I'll just add the to-manys as sets in the dictionary with the key as their relationship name.

Comment: When creating managed objects from a dictionary, Core Data will automatically set up inverse relationships for you, so going back shouldn't be that hard. It will also make your display code simpler if you're dealing with the data in one form.